# angular 2 rc1 how to import external js library

Tags: typescript, angular, jointjs

I am trying to use joint.js with Angular 2. Here is what I did.

index.html

```
<!-- JoinJS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jointjs/0.9.7/joint.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jointjs/0.9.7/joint.js"></script>
```

config.js

```
  var  map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'https://npmcdn.com/angular2-in-memory-web-api', // get latest
    'joint':                      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jointjs/0.9.7/joint.js'
  };

  //packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.ts',  defaultExtension: 'ts' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'joint': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
```

service.ts

```
//declare var joint: any;
import * as joint from 'joint';
```

I got error "[ts] Could not find module joint".

What's missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include typings declaration file so that ts compiler could understand. install typings globally (**npm install -g typings**) and then install jointjs typings (**typings install dt~jointjs --save --global**) file. 
For refrence, see [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/typescript-configuration.html) and [this](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/)

Comment: does typings install command generate .d.ts file? In order to run typings install command I have to install joint.js first and cannot simply use <script> in index.html to reference joint.js?

Comment: Yes. Typings will generate .d.ts file. And I am not sure of using <script> in index.html refer .d.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

> I got error "[ts] Could not find module joint".

FWIW the generated javascript will still be fine [more](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html).

## Quick Fix

You need to *declare* the module in a `foo.d.ts` file:

```
declare module "join" {
var foo:any;
export = foo;
}
```

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html